# Save list in key/value pair in Consul

Tags: ansible, consul

I suppose this could be for any key/value storage type but I'm mainly using Consul for storage. I need a way to save a list in the value of a key. However, the quotes around the elements are stripped.

I've tried them all, the problem is I need them to return as a valid list so that i can run it through Ansible w/ `with_flattened`

```
curl -X PUT -d '['ui','dashboard']' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/deploylist
curl -X PUT -d '[\'ui\',\'dashboard']' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/deploylist
```

Ansible tasks:

```
- debug: msg="{{ deploylist_vars.value | map(attribute='Value') | first }}"
  register: module_id

# Output 
"msg": "[ui,dashboard]"
```

I need to loop through the list and perform further actions. However, I can't seem to parse the elements correctly.

```
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_flattened:
    - "{{ module_id }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of those quotings looks quite right. I expect you want something JSON-like to be PUT, probably `["ui","dashboard"]`. The following should get bash/zsh to pass that through:

```
curl -X PUT -d '["ui","dashboard"]' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/deploylist
```

You could further do some backslash-escaping inside the single quotes, but don’t add more single quotes without some care.